# Query returns no result (Delphi, Oracle, DBExpress)

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbexpress

I am trying to get the query result from the Oracle sql server and insert it in the `StringGridShowPapers` table.

I have `SQLConnection1` (a DBExpress connection) set up and working, `SQLDataSetPapers` DataSet and a query `SQLQueryPapers`.

When I am running this procedure, the query seems to return nothing:

```
procedure TFormOperator.TabSheetShowPapersShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
    SQLQueryShowPapers.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM papers';
    SQLQueryShowPapers.Open;
    SQLQueryShowPapers.First;

    if (NOT SQLQueryShowPapers.IsEmpty) then begin
        SQLQueryShowPapers.First;
        StringGridShowPapers.RowCount := 2;

        while (NOT SQLQueryShowPapers.EOF) do begin
            if (SQLQueryShowPapers.Fields[2].AsString = Frame11.ID) then begin
                with StringGridShowPapers do begin
                  Cells[0, (StringGridShowPapers.RowCount - 1)] :=
                    SQLQueryShowPapers.Fields[0].AsString;
                  Cells[1, (StringGridShowPapers.RowCount - 1)] :=
                    SQLQueryShowPapers.Fields[1].AsString;
                  Cells[2, (StringGridShowPapers.RowCount - 1)] :=
                    SQLQueryShowPapers.Fields[2].AsString;
                end;
                SQLQueryShowPapers.Next;
                StringGridShowPapers.RowCount := StringGridShowPapers.RowCount + 1;
            end;
        end;
    end;

end;
```

`Frame11.ID` contains a string value  of a number.

Running the same query `SELECT * FROM papers` in oracle SQL Developer results a number of rows.

What could trigger the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Looks like i found the **solution**:

It looks like the some (global) variables and properties in Delphi are inaccessable or simply cleaned up after the procedure that assigns them is finished. So you may need to assign first form value to a global variable of second one (that you use this value in) in a runtime of the first form procedure.

Comment: `SQLQueryShowPapers.Next;` is inside `IF BEGIN... END` . you need move it out from the `IF`

Comment: @are thanks for noticing this! But the problem still didn't go

Comment: I am not even getting into first condition

Comment: `IsEmpty` was buggy at some time. You may use `if not (Query.Bof and Query.Eof) then`. Except that, move that `Next` call outside the `if` block and remove both `First` calls.

Comment: @Victoria, thanks, i've changed the condotion, but the problem still exists

Comment: If you're getting zero rows, that means you have no rows that are matching `Frame11.ID`. From whatever query utility you're using, run `SELECT * FROM papers WHERE <youridfield> = '<Frame11IDValue>'` and see if you get rows. (Clearly, replace `<youridfield>` with the name of the column that you reference with `Fields[0]` in your code, and `<Frame11IDValue>` with the string value of `Frame11.ID` from your code.)

Comment: Alright, it looks like the some (global) variables and properties in Delphi are inaccessable or simply cleaned up after the procedure that assigns them is finished. So you may need to assign first form value to a global variable of second one (that you use this value in) in a runtime of the first form procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of flaws in your code.

First, you don't need `IsEmpty`, and you don't need either call to `First`. When you first open a query, the dataset is automatically set at the first row, and you can omit `IsEmpty` if you know you're going to iterate over the rows.

Second, you should never `SELECT` without a `WHERE` clause and then filter the data afterward. The only reason to `SELECT` without a `WHERE` is if you're absolutely certain you need every single row (and column) from the table. If you don't, add a `WHERE` in order to limit the number of rows that are returned from the server (and to avoid having to write so much code to filter it on the client side).

Try something like this instead. I don't know what datatype `Fields[2]` or `Frame11.ID` are, so I'm going to treat them as `string` as your existing code does. If they're not strings, then change both references to the actual data type needed. I'm also going to presume that `Fields[2].FieldName` is `ID`; again, if it's not, change the code accordingly.

```
procedure TFormOperator.TabSheetShowPapersShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  GridRow: Integer;
begin
  SQLQueryShowPapers.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM papers WHERE ID = :ID';
  SQLQueryShowPapers.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value := Frame11.ID;
  SQLQueryShowPapers.Open;  // No need for First. Happens automatically

  StringGridShowPapers.RowCount := 1;

  // No need for IsEmpty. If no rows were returned, this loop will not be entered
  while not SQLQueryShowPapers.EOF do
  begin
    StringGridShowPapers.RowCount := StringGridShowPapers.RowCount + 1;
    GridRow := StringGridShowPapers.RowCount - 1;

    StringGridShowPapers.Cells[0, GridRow] := SQLQueryShowPapers.Fields[0].AsString;
    StringGridShowPapers.Cells[1, GridRow] := SQLQueryShowPapers.Fields[1].AsString;
    StringGridShowPapers.Cells[2, GridRow] := SQLQueryShowPapers.Fields[2].AsString;
    SQLQueryShowPapers.Next;
  end;
end;
```

As an aside, I'd do a couple of things:

- Most importantly, stop using `SELECT *` and actually list the columns you need. It's easier to maintain the code, and it reduces overhead of moving data from the server across the network that you're not going to use.
- Also, stop using hard-coded references to field positions (`Fields[0]`, `Fields[1]`, etc.). It's error prone, it will bite you in the backside when a column changes in the future, and it makes the code impossible to maintain 6 months from now when you don't remember exactly what order the columns are in or someone else needs to work with your code. Either add persistent fields to your query or use `FieldByName` to retrieve them by name.
- Shorten the variable names to avoid typing somewhat. `SQLQueryShowPapers`, for instance, could just be `QryPapers` (unless you have some other type of query than a SQL query, that is), and `StringGridShowPapers` could be `GridPapers` or `PaperGrid`.
- You'll note I added a local integer variable `GridRow` to reduce the typing required for all the repeated calls to `StringGridShowPapers.RowCount - 1` in every access to `Cells`.
- You'll also note I made it simpler to deal with adding new rows to `StringGridShowPapers` in the loop.
- I also removed the need to test `Fields[0].AsString = Frame11.ID` by adding a parameter and a `WHERE` clause to your SQL statement. It also reduces the amount of data that has to pass from the server across the network, reduces the memory requirements of your application, and cuts the amount of time you spend unnecessarily reading rows you won't be using and skipping them (iterations through the loop). In other words, I removed the entire `if` test.
- Lastly, you could reduce this entire code down to three lines (setting the SQL.Text, assigning a value to the parameter, and opening the query) if you got rid of the `TStringGrid` entirely and used a `TDBGrid` instead. It's specifically designed to display data from a dataset. All you do is add the `TDBGrid` to your form in place of the `TStringGrid`, drop a `TDataSource` as well, connect the `TDBGrid.DataSource to the`TDataSource`and the`TDataSource.DataSet` to your query. Then open your query as usual, and the grid is automatically populated with the data with zero lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for advices!) Will do so

Answer (score 0):

try this, the `next` operator is out of `if` block
I think something in your data doesn't let you cycle to be completed

```
procedure TFormOperator.TabSheetShowPapersShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
    SQLQueryShowPapers.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM papers';
    SQLQueryShowPapers.Open;
    SQLQueryShowPapers.First;

    if (NOT SQLQueryShowPapers.IsEmpty) then begin
        SQLQueryShowPapers.First;
        StringGridShowPapers.RowCount := 2;

        while (NOT SQLQueryShowPapers.EOF) do begin
            if (SQLQueryShowPapers.Fields[2].AsString = Frame11.ID) then begin
                with StringGridShowPapers do begin
                  Cells[0, (StringGridShowPapers.RowCount - 1)] :=
                    SQLQueryShowPapers.Fields[0].AsString;
                  Cells[1, (StringGridShowPapers.RowCount - 1)] :=
                    SQLQueryShowPapers.Fields[1].AsString;
                  Cells[2, (StringGridShowPapers.RowCount - 1)] :=
                    SQLQueryShowPapers.Fields[2].AsString;
                end;
                StringGridShowPapers.RowCount := StringGridShowPapers.RowCount + 1;
            end;
             SQLQueryShowPapers.Next;
        end;
    end;

end;
```

Comment: did that, still same empty query output